# Changing the bone position with a shape key

Tags: rigging, bones, shape-keys

I've been looking and I haven't been able to find this anywhere. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I want to create an animation where a human character morphs into a monster. The shape I have in mind, the fingers would extend into a more nightmarish claw shape where the fingers extend along with the fingernails. The character is rigged, so how do I change the bone positions so they match the geometry shape that I've created? Is there a means to reposition the bones so that they still work properly when you activate the shape key? Has someone done a tutorial on this sort of thing?

Comment: I dont think this is possible, because this must modify the weights which is not animatable. Probably you have to swap the model and the rig after the transformation.

Comment: I've seen it done in the video for Universal Human rig on Gumroad. I'm not sure if it'll let me most a link to the video but it seems like this person accomplished it. [link](https://youtu.be/TPXzUTI9oc4)